AttributeError: module 'fluidsynth' has no attribute 'synth'
import fluidsynth

fs = fluidsynth.synth()
fs.start(driver = 'dsound')  # use DirectSound driver

sfid = fs.sfload(r'C:\Users\135697\Documents\FluidR3_GM.sf2')  # replace path as needed
fs.program_select(0, sfid, 0, 0)

fs.noteon(0, 60, 30)
fs.noteon(0, 67, 30)
fs.noteon(0, 76, 30)

time.sleep(3.0)

fs.noteoff(0, 60)
fs.noteoff(0, 67)
fs.noteoff(0, 76)

time.sleep(1.0)

fs.delete()

This is my code, I'm using VSCode. For some reason, it says that fluidsynth doesn't have an attribute synth. I have installed both fluidsynth and pyfluidsynth already. Is there a reason why this isn't working?
I've tried uninstalling fluidsynth, and this is running in a .venv virtual environment.

Is it fluidsynth.synth() or fluidsynth.Synth() (note the capital S)?

I’ve been doing lowercase

And what happens if you change it to upper case?

Nothing happens when I change between the two.

What is the error message when you make it .Synth() with a capital S  rather than .synth()?

The error stays the same.
